# jquery if/else statement with .get not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

On a new-user registration form, I have a real simple function just to check to see if a username exists in the database. Unfortunately, the `else` part of the statement isn't working. The PHP file works fine and returns either `true` or `false`, as expected. Here's the jQuery:

```
$('#username').keyup(function() {
        var inp = $('#username').val();
        $.get('register-check-username.php', { username: inp }, function(data) {
            if(data!="false") {
                $('#namecheck').html('✓');
            } else {
                $('#namecheck').html('This username is already taken');
            }
         });
    });
```

If it's not clear, `username` is the id of the text input. When it's changed the php is checking username availability. Then a `<span>` tag with id "namecheck" is to change to tell the user what's up. Now, I can change `if(data)` to `if(!data)` and it will behave as expected for that change. As it is above, I can get `$('#namecheck').html('✓')` to happen when it's supposed to, but never the second part of `$('#namecheck').html('This username is already taken')`.

Why is my `else` line never being called? I've wasted too much time trying to figure this out on my own so now I'm asking you all for some help in figuring out what's going wrong.

edit:
With `console.log(data)` in there, the console returns `false` when it's false, but nothing is logged when it's true.

Updated `if(data)` to `if(data!="false")`. The problem remains.

**UPDATE**
The problem isn't quite what I thought it was. It looks like the script *is* firing as it should, except it only does `.keyup` if the input value is 4 characters or less, and the username I've been testing it with is 6 letters. The data returned for the first 4 characters stays put.

So now it looks like the problem is actually that it won't run `.get()` unless the value is 4 characters or less. I'm looking into what might be causing this in the php.

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show ?

Comment: it shows 'false' when it's false and nothing when it's true. i put it right below the `var inp` line

Comment: Can you change your php to echo `true` as else to the `false` that is already working?

Comment: the php already says either true or false depending on the presence of that username in the database. maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: _"nothing is logged when it's true"_ - Are you saying that an empty string gets logged, or that nothing happens at all (implying some kind of error). Are you sure the callback function is actually getting called for the true case?

Comment: nothing happens at all. i'm sure there's an error keeping the true case from being called. I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: If the php would echo true then you would have a console.log(data) giving "true", if its empty your error is in the php

Comment: Assuming the `console.log()` is _before_ the `if` then you should get either "true" or "false" logged if the function gets called at all. Try adding `.fail()` and `.always()` handlers as shown in [the `$.get()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and see if they get called.

Comment: See the update in the description. `.fail()` happens any time the input is more than 4 letters long. Up to that point it runs fine. That turns out to be the real problem.

Comment: If I have `.fail()` and `.done()` log something to the console, then it works. If I don't, then it doesn't work past 4 characters. What's up with that.

Answer (score 4):

(data) will always be a truthy value since it is a string

Change to

```
if (data=="true") ...
```

If true returns empty (not a clever idea) try

```
if (data!="false") ...
```

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wq6kT/)

Comment: I've tried both of those and I'm running into the same issue. It only changes (or logs to console) if it's false, never when it's true. The `else` statement is still being ignored.

Comment: Then your call is not correct. Can you show what `register-check-username.php?username+existinguser` returns ?

Comment: if I go to the php page as register-check-username.php?username=existinguser it echoes 'true'

Comment: And if you do `register-check-username.php?username+nonexistinguser`

Answer (score 1):

Some time what happened you will return true/false in boolean or simple string format so, Javascript will not understand that.

for that you should make condition like that.

```
if( data === true || data === "true" || data === 1 || data === "1" )
{
 // Do something here
}
else
{
 // Do something else
}
```